# Using Postgresql with Grails : Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

I'm having trouble with Grails 2.0 and Postgresql 9.1

I'm trying to map an existing database, with sequential ids.
However, even without creating any class in the domain, I'm having the error :

```
Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Error  executing bootstraps:
      Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; 
      nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
      Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
      (...)
      Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException:
           Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence
```

My Datasource is :

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    username = "postgres"
    password = "postgrespass"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    logSql = true
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "" 
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Rambo"
        }
    }
}
```

Tee exisiting database is a Poker software database (Holdem manager). I was working on a PlayerHand object that doesn't use a sequence, but the Player object has a sequence table.

What is strange is that on a previous program, I was quite easily able to make the Player object working with Postgresql 8.3 & Grails 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have one of the entities using a sequence ID generator without any sequence name configured, and Hibernate thus uses the default sequence name: hibernate_sequence, but doesn't find it.

Configure the sequence name (and use an existing sequence), or create the hibernate_sequence sequence in database, or don't use a sequence-based generator.

Comment: The configuration between Grails 1.x and Grails 2.0 seems to change on this subject. I've been able to configure it using GRAG.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure Postgres to use one sequence per table - I described that here: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/One-hibernate-sequence-is-used-for-all-Postgres-tables-td1351722.html

But you'll still need to create the sequence(s). `dbCreate='update'` doesn't create sequences (only `create` and `create-drop` do) so you'll need to manually create them or use a migration tool like http://www.grails.org/plugin/database-migration

Comment: The thing is that my grails application will work against Database I can't touch. So I can't migrate it.

Comment: What's the primary key type in the database? You just need to adjust the `mapping` block to use whatever is in the database. If there's an existing sequence you can use, add `id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'seq_foo']` substituting the correct name.

Comment: The custom dialect solution is what I used and I found it to be the most effective to avoid me having to put `id generator` in all my domains.  This also allowed me to keep maximum portability as now the sequence control is defined in the dialect instead of the actual model (not all DB engines support sequence).  Thanks Burt!

Comment: I used this in Grails 3 to enable PostgreSQL functionality as well.